# Comparing Rate of Hydrolysis of Acyl halides

Tags: organic-chemistry, kinetics, hydrolysis, nucleophilicity, steric-effects

[image]

In this particular question, my answer is (D) as steric hinderance is minimum there, but answer (B) was given due to the electron withdrawing (**-M**) effect of the nitro group.

Isn't steric hinderance the dominating factor in nucleophilic addition type reactions? Is it that a planar phenyl ring doesn't offer that much steric hinderance?

Comment: @Jay Yes knew it , but problem was that steric hinderance should've been more dominating factor than this ?

Comment: Both are 1° carbon but your view can't be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The high reactivity of acyl chlorides towards nucleophilic attack is due to the highly polarised situation of the carbon-oxygen/chlorine bonds i.e.

[image]

As you have mentioned due to the phenyl ring being planar, the steric hindrance does not overpower the polarising thing.

Now on comparing the reactions **-NO$_2$** group's **-M** effect will be the most successful to make the carbon-oxygen/chlorine bonds more polar as compared to **methyl's +I** effect.

Comment: Yes , seems right

Comment: I disagree. [This](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01303a039) paper compares the rates of alcoholysis of various acid chlorides and it is found that acetyl chloride has a much higher rate than p-nitro benzoyl chloride.

Comment: @RobinSingh the paper is not explicitly showing any comparison between p-nitro benzoyl chloride and acetyl chloride. It does talks about ethyl p-nitrobenzoate which is a different compound.

Comment: @DivyanshVerma It does lol. Check Table I and II on page 4

Comment: I don't have access to the whole pdf